# How to split sequence diagram in Visual Paradigm

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

I'm drawing a Sequence Diagram in Visual Paradigm, but it is getting bigger and bigger. How could I split it in multiple sequence diagrams in a proper way?

I tried copying (or cutting) and pasting to the new diagram with no success. I googled a bit with no result.

Comment: If your SD grows too big you probably have to cut down the complexty of the aspect you try to highlight and make it a couple of smaller aspects you can link with Fragments.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, but I have drawn several operations and I would like to move to another SD instead of deleting and rewrite it. Do you know how to do it? copy-paste doesn't work.

Comment: you cannot duplicate the diagram then remove parts on original and clone ?

Comment: You are right @bruno, I could do it in that way. It is needed to select the whole diagram and copy paste. Thanks!